# What should I expect from a paper discussion in a postdoc interview?

Tags: postdocs, interview, presentation

I have been invited for a postdoc interview that includes a paper discussion. They sent me their key paper and told me to discuss it because I will do something similar if hired. I read the paper and have understood it but I do not know what to expect.

Comment: You should expect that they'll want to talk about the paper and the job they may hire you to do. What specifically are you asking?

Answer (score 5):

A simple question might be if you agree with the conclusions. A bit more intense is how it relates to your work. Even more would be what sorts of extensions might be looked into.

It would be worth knowing whether they have any vested interest in the paper or not.

They might also start with asking you for an overview.

The other questions would be more typical as how do you see yourself fitting in to their research program and/or how independent you want/need to be.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting technique. Though I haven't seen that in that bluntness, I can imagine what they may be interested in.

They probably want you to work on the field, and based on that paper. So, I would expect:

1. can you explain the model, techniques, results?
2. can you make suggestions on what is missing and how you might consider extending it?
3. would you like working on this direction and extend the work?
4. do you see alternatives or relevant related work?

As I am not on the interview committee, this is only an educated guess, but that's what I would do if we had sent out such a request.